# My laptop keeps locking on lid close, ignoring my settings

Tags: system-settings

Whenever I close my laptop's lid, it locks and I have to enter my password to get it to resume. In my power settings, I have selected "Do nothing" for the option "When lid is closed" for both "On battery power" and "When plugged in" state.

What's going on?

Comment: I think the problem might be confusion over what the terms "suspend" and "resume" means.  "Suspends" means your computer goes into sleep mode.  "Resume" means waking it up.  What you mean is that you need to enter your password to *unlock* the screen.  I think you're just referring to the screensaver coming on and locking the screen, which is a different setting than the ones you're looking at.

Comment: Yeah, I probably worded that wrong. My main concern is that it requires to be resumed at all. I want absolutely nothing to happen when I close the lid. How can I do this?

Comment: Look under screensaver settings.  Uncheck the option to lock the screen.

Comment: I looked through everything under System Settings and there doesn't seem to be any other settings like this besides some settings under "Power" and "Brightness and Lock", which I've set to my desired outcome.

Comment: Ok.  It's been a while since I looked at Unity settings (I don't use Unity anymore).  What did you set for "Brightness and Lock"?  Locking the screen means you will have this behavior when you close the lid.

Comment: My current settings: [Brightness and Lock](http://i.imgur.com/OEblF.png) / [Power](http://i.imgur.com/LG7h8.png)

Comment: Do you have to unlock your screen if you close your lid and open it before 5 minutes?

Comment: I set "Lock" to off, seems to be working now. Little confusing, I should've figured that out though. Thanks!

Comment: See a reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/995840

Answer (score 5):

Possible workaround: In System Settings > Brightness and Lock switch off 'Lock'. The downside is that your system also cannot lock anymore after a set time.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11880774

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1974398

Answer (score 2):

I think completing the bug report from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/995840/ might get this fixed. Thanks!

Comment: this derivative one as well:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/1001908